# Sending System Event on Android

Tags: android, testing

I want to send various system event from my test application so that i can test that, my original application can properly handle all those system related events.

This issue right now bit important for me as my application handling some system event which are not vary frequent.

Example events but not limited to

1. Battery Plugged
2. 3G/2G Switch
3. Charger Plugged

Will appreciate any help on this.

Comment: So are you trying to implement a service that will listen for these events, or just an application that will tell you if these things are true/false?

Comment: Yes you are right. I have a BroadcastReceiver for receiving those events

Comment: Okay, make sure you have access to those things in your manifest.  Then post the code where you are trying to do these things.  We're not here to write your project for you :)

Comment: I am not looking for source code or sample project i am looking for idea. I can write code well enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try "Hardware Events Emulation" and "Device Power Characteristics" from the emulator console as described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#console).